# Default `const vector<int> &id` argument in function

Tags: c++, vector

I have the following function:

```
double Fitter(double EBeam, vector<KFParticle>
&MeasParticle, vector<TLorentzVector> &RecoParticle,
const vector<int> &id) {  
   do something
}
```

But sometimes I do no want to provide the last argument (`id` vector ). I need something like this:

```
double Fitter( ..., const vector<int> &id = empty_vector )
```

But I do not want to create some static vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can default-construct an empty vector inline:

```
double Fitter( ..., const vector<int> &id = std::vector<int>{} )
```

Since `id` is a constant-reference it will work.

Comment: It helps, Thanks.

Comment: If your compiler accepts `= std::vector<int>{}`, it will also accept `= {}` which makes the code easier to read and doesn't violate DRY.

Answer (score 3):

In this case, the answer from @Some programmer dude is perfect (please upvote his if you find it useful):

```
double Fitter( ..., const vector<int> &id = std::vector<int>{} )
```

---

In case you find a case where you *cannot* implement a default because it's dynamic, you can write an overload:

```
double Fitter(double EBeam,
              vector<KFParticle> &MeasParticle, 
              vector<TLorentzVector> &RecoParticle,
              const vector<int> &id) 
{  
    // ... do something 
}

double Fitter(double EBeam,
              vector<KFParticle> &MeasParticle, 
              vector<TLorentzVector> &RecoParticle) 
{ 
  vector<int> id; // you could do something dynamic here instead
  return Fitter(EBeam, MeasParticle, RecoParticle, id);
}
```